# Matplotlib rcparams (autolimit_mode) for single figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue with the new Matplotlib 2.0.0.

The new autolimit_mode value by default add a padding to the frame.
I want to avoid it to a single figure.

If I change rcParams, the changes affect to any generated figures.

Can I change this parameter for a single figure without affect the behavior of the rest?

---

**Update**

I update the question with some code and the different results obtained.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def remove_frame_border(ax):
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)


def draw1(xserie, yserie):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot(xserie, yserie)
    ax.grid(True)
    remove_frame_border(ax)

    fig.savefig('out1.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)


def draw2(xserie, yserie):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    # Fixed autolimit padding in matplotlib 2.0.0
    ax.set_xmargin(0)
    ax.set_ymargin(0)
    ax.autoscale_view()

    ax.plot(xserie, yserie)
    ax.grid(True)
    remove_frame_border(ax)

    # Restore default matplotlib params
    matplotlib.rcParams.update(matplotlib.rcParamsDefault)

    fig.savefig('out2.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)


def draw3(xserie, yserie):
    # Fixed autolimit padding in matplotlib 2.0.0
    matplotlib.rcParams['axes.autolimit_mode'] = 'round_numbers'
    matplotlib.rcParams['axes.xmargin'] = 0
    matplotlib.rcParams['axes.ymargin'] = 0

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,3))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.plot(xserie, yserie)
    ax.grid(True)
    remove_frame_border(ax)

    # Restore default matplotlib params
    matplotlib.rcParams.update(matplotlib.rcParamsDefault)

    fig.savefig('out3.png', format='png', bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0)



xserie = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
yserie = np.array([0, 22.2, 33.4, 55.6, 66.6, 77.7, 100.3, 123.3, 90.4, 93.3])

draw1(xserie, yserie)
draw2(xserie, yserie)
draw3(xserie, yserie)
```

- draw1 is the default behavior
- draw2 call ax.set_xmargin and ax.set_ymargin
- draw3 change the rcParams and restore it after generate the chart

**out1.png**
[image: out1.png]

**out2.png**
[image: out2.png]

**out3.png**
[image: out3.png]

Answer (score 1):

Matplotlib provides the method [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xmargin`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xmargin.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-set-xmargin):

> Set padding of X data limits prior to autoscaling. `m` times the data
>   interval will be added to each end of that interval before it is used
>   in autoscaling.

So setting

```
ax.set_xmargin(0)
```

removes the padding.

However it seems for this to have an effect, one also needs to call
[`matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale_view`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.autoscale_view.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-autoscale-view)

```
ax.autoscale_view()
```

I did not entirely understand the docstring of `autoscale_view` but the combination here seems to work.

Comment: What are "the last gridlines"? In your question there are no gridlines. It is always next to impossible to discuss some undesired behaviour without knowing the code or an image or a very detailed descrition of the issue.

Comment: I have updated my first post with some code and examples. With last grid line I mean the last tick line in the grid. If I remove the frame border I miss the y =140 and x = 10 line in the chart

Comment: There is no gridline at x=10, as this would already be outside the axes. You wouldn't see this if you were not removing all the spines. Now you can of course set the limits to your needs, e.g. `ax.set_xlim((1,10.01))` or setting the margin still a little higher as to include the rightmost gridline as well, `ax.set_xmargin(0.001)`. Those solution might however strongly depend on the data you plot.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to do a auxiliar function to adjust the "extra margin" depending on the data. I can use the tick frequency from ax.get_yticks() and set the upper limit as: `ticks = ax.get_yticks(); max_tick = np.max(ticks); freq = ticks[1] - ticks[0]; upper_limit = max_tick + freq if np.max(yserie) > max_tick else max_tick`