# how do I apply 'tight' layout to all subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, layout, subplot, x-axis

plt.axis('tight') applies only on the last axis.  How do I apply it to all three axises on the figure?

The data source looks like this.

[image]

And the code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
patterns = [ "\\" , "/" , "-","+" ,"x", "|",":",  "<",  "O" ]
file_locn4 = ''r'data.csv'''
df = pd.read_csv(file_locn4)

grouped = df.groupby('A')

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(5,3))#,sharey=True)

for (name, df), ax in zip(grouped, axs.flat):
    df.plot(x='dataset',kind='bar', ax=ax,legend=False)
handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
for ax in fig.axes:
    bars = ax.patches
    hatches = ''.join(h*len(df) for h in patterns)

    for bar, hatch in zip(bars, hatches):
        bar.set_hatch(2*hatch)

ax.legend(loc=1, bbox_to_anchor=(.70, 1.16), ncol=4)  # ,fontsize=14)
for ax in fig.axes:
    plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=360)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.savefig('fig.pdf')
plt.show()
```

Output looks like this[image]

I want all three subplots to look like the last one(subplot D)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [matplotlib axis('tight') doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45666740/matplotlib-axistight-doesnt-work)

Comment: It does not answer my question.

Comment: It does answer your question - call `ax.autoscale(tight=True)` for each of your axes.